# Are Interfaces counted as Functional Dependency?

Tags: software-engineering

I'm doing some homework where I have to count the number of functional dependencies (direct and indirect).

But then I'm faced with an unexpected situation, where a class has a relation with an interface. I can find no bibliography on the subject and the teacher didn't talk about this.

Intuituvely, I thought as it being a dependency, for it is used as parameter and attribute of the analyzed class. But should I also count its implementations as dependencies? They are not referenced directly, but can be used in a polymorphic approach.

Here's a basic example for understanding (its not the exercise, but something that came to my mind quickly to explain):

[image: Example Diagram]

Comment: While I think your question fits the scope of CS SE well, I think it fits the Programmers SE perfectly. You will probably receive a more detailed answer there.